# Is there any standard order for nesting JWS and JWE tokens?

Tags: json, jwt, jwe

I need to pass JSON-encoded signed (and sometimes additionally encrypted) objects between multiple instances of my software. The obvious choice here is JWT.

Yet, JWT allows apparently to both sign and encrypt a token (JWS and JWE) or nest JWS into a JWE (nested JWE).

While both approaches seem reasonable for me, is there a "standard" way of doing this? I haven't found any specifics on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Short answer

When both signing and encryption are necessary, you should first sign the message and then encrypt the result. That is, nesting a JWS into a JWE is a valid approach.

### Long answer

[JSON Web Token](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519) (JWT) is an open standard that defines a compact and self-contained way for securely transmitting information between parties as a JSON object. JWT is a *generic name* for the following types of token:

- [JSON Web Signature](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7515) (JWS): The payload is *encoded and signed* so the *integrity* of the claims can be verified.
- [JSON Web Encryption](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7516) (JWE): They payload is *encrypted* so the claims are *hidden* from other parties.

[image: JWT, JWS and JWE]
<sup>The image was extracted from this [page](https://medium.facilelogin.com/jwt-jws-and-jwe-for-not-so-dummies-b63310d201a3).</sup>

> JWT allows apparently to both sign and encrypt a token (JWS and JWE) or nest JWS into a JWE (nested JWE).
>
> While both approaches seem reasonable for me, is there a "standard" way of doing this? I haven't found any specifics on this.

The concept of *nested JWT* is defined in the [RFC 7519](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519):

> A JWT in which nested signing and/or encryption are employed.  In
> Nested JWTs, a JWT is used as the payload or plaintext value of an
> enclosing JWS or JWE structure, respectively.

Regarding the order of the operations, it's advisable to *first sign the message and then encrypt the result*, as mentioned in the same document:

> [**11.2.  Signing and Encryption Order**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-11.2)
>
> While syntactically the signing and encryption operations for *Nested
> JWTs* may be applied in any order, if both signing and encryption are
> necessary, normally producers should sign the message and then
> encrypt the result (thus encrypting the signature).  This prevents
> attacks in which the signature is stripped, leaving just an encrypted
> message, as well as providing privacy for the signer.  Furthermore,
> signatures over encrypted text are not considered valid in many
> jurisdictions.